# R. Create dataframe with conditional combinations of elements from vector

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have a vector with around 600 unique elements: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, etc. Using R, I would like to get a dataframe with 4 columns, where each row has all possible combinations of 4 elements under the following conditions:

1. "A" goes always in column 1.
2. Column 2 has B or C.
3. Columns 3 and 4 have pairs of the remaining elements (pair X, Y is considered equal to pair Y, X). I expect to get something like:

   1    2    3    4
   A    B    D    E
   A    B    F    G
   A    B    H    I
   A    C    D    E
   A    C    F    G
   A    C    H    I

Comment: What would be the number of rows of expected output

Comment: May be `v1 <- LETTERS[1:9]; out <- expand.grid(v1[1], v1[2:3], combn(v1[-(1:3)], 2, FUN = paste, collapse=" "), stringsAsFactors = FALSE); out[c('Var3', 'Var4' )] <- read.table(text = out$Var3, header = FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you @akrun. But remember that the vector has 600 elements and many of them are combinations of letters, numbers and other characters (I forgot to mention that, I am sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using `combn()`, `expand.grid()` and `tidyr::separate` based on @akrun's comment.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

vec_a <- LETTERS[1]
vec_b <- LETTERS[2:3]
vec_c <- LETTERS[4:26]
vec_d <- combn(vec_c, 2, FUN = paste, collapse = " ")

res <- expand.grid(vec_a, vec_b, vec_d) %>% 
  tidyr::separate(Var3, c("Var3","Var4"), " ")

head(res, 25)
#>    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
#> 1     A    B    D    E
#> 2     A    C    D    E
#> 3     A    B    D    F
#> 4     A    C    D    F
#> 5     A    B    D    G
#> 6     A    C    D    G
#> 7     A    B    D    H
#> 8     A    C    D    H
#> 9     A    B    D    I
#> 10    A    C    D    I
#> 11    A    B    D    J
#> 12    A    C    D    J
#> 13    A    B    D    K
#> 14    A    C    D    K
#> 15    A    B    D    L
#> 16    A    C    D    L
#> 17    A    B    D    M
#> 18    A    C    D    M
#> 19    A    B    D    N
#> 20    A    C    D    N
#> 21    A    B    D    O
#> 22    A    C    D    O
#> 23    A    B    D    P
#> 24    A    C    D    P
#> 25    A    B    D    Q
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcelo Avila !